# How do I set the font of an UI element to the "System" font in IB?

Tags: iphone, uifont

How do I set the font of an UI element (ex. UILabel) to the "System" font in IB?

In code, I know I can do the following:

```
UIFont * tempFont = [[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24] retain];
```

But what about doing the same thing in IB?  What is the default system font on the IPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to find out programmatically (NSLog the result), and set that in interface builder. You won't be sure that the result will be the font in the future however.

By the way, this might be a useful site too: http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts

Comment: i just found that site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no default system font, per se, because it's dependent upon the language the phone is set to. Helvetica is used pretty much wherever Latin characters are used, but another font could be easily substituted when the Latin character set won't suffice. `systemFontOfSize` allows the OS to use the system font for the language in question.